# REST resource permissions

Tags: file, api, rest, permissions

I am creating a REST API for my next project. I am not sure what the best way to handle read / write permissions on resources is. Some resources will be readable by anyone, others will only be readable by "logged in" users, others will only be readable by specific users or admins. This also goes for write access.

How are these permissions stored and validated in REST APIs. Are there simply database tables that store the permissions for each resource or the permissions each user has to each resource? This approach seems like it could become bloated if there were many resources to keep track of not to mention every database query would require a JOIN to the table that contains permissions.

Thanks for your input in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How your server side *stores* authentication and authorization data is entirely up to the server. It may use a database, it may use files, or none of the above.

From the perspective of RESTful HTTP, the point is that client might try to access some resource, the server **may** answer with 401 (Unathorized/Authentication required) or 403 (Fordbidden) HTTP error codes to enforce login/permission requirements.

Also remember, that not all services map directly to one or more relational database queries. In other words, plan to implement the authentication/authorization logic independently of the "data" if you can, and if you need fine-grained access restrictions, try to do it in code instead of joining stuff in the database, if it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I understand what you mean. I know that this is probably a pretty broad topic so I will mark your answer as correct. I will try and do some additional reading based on what you have said.